# How to disable input field once adaptive cards appear in microsoft chatbot?

Tags: node.js, azure, chatbot

I am using node js with microsoft bot for webchat.where I need to disable input text box once adaptive card appear and it should enable once the adaptive card disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable fields on Adaptive Card.

You can check the 'Schema Explorer' to view all properties of every Input:
[Schema Explorer](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.Text.html)

Answer (score 0):

As it's already mentioned that is not possible to enable/disable an Input.Text. My suggestion is to use a TextBlock instead, so users can not change the value.